# Adding an SVG that has 3 paths to the .innerHTML part of a button

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to add an `SVG` that has 3 paths to a button code. I know how to do One Path, but doing multiple, I am confused on how to do that.

I need help adding the `SVG` to the `.innerHTML` part of the code.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/hnhqtb4u/2/

**Play:**

```
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
<path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="orange"></path>
<path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
<path d="M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z" fill="blue"></path></svg>
```

**Pause:**

```
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
<path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="red"></path>
<path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
<path d="M27.9,21h-3.7c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v22.8c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h3.7c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1V22.1 C29,21.5,28.5,21,27.9,21zM40.9,21h-3.7c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v22.8c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h3.7c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1V22.1 C42,21.5,41.5,21,40.9,21z" fill="blue"></path>
</svg>
```

Below is the code format I'm using.

**Button Code:**

```
<button id="playButton2" style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer; background-color: black; border: 3px solid #0059dd;"
  onclick=" 
var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
var player = document.getElementById('player2');
player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
playButton2.innerHTML = '&lt;svg width=\'65\' height=\'109\' style=\'stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width:3px;\' viewBox=\'-1 0 62 100\'&gt;&lt;path fill=\'currentColor\' d=\'M0 8c0-5 3-8 8-8s9 3 9 8v84c0 5-4 8-9 8s-8-3-8-8V8zm43 0c0-5 3-8 8-8s8 3 8 8v84c0 5-3 8-8 8s-8-3-8-8V8z\'&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;';
player.play();
} else {
playButton2.innerHTML = '&lt;svg width=\'92\' height=\'109\' style=\'stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width:3px;\' viewBox=\'0 -3 85 106\'&gt;&lt;path fill=\'currentColor\' d=\'M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z\'&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;';
player.pause();
}">
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
<path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="orange"></path>
<path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
<path d="M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z" fill="blue"></path>
</svg>

</button>

<audio id="player2" style="display:none;">
  <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: Have you considered just putting them in the code, and using `style="display:none"` to hide the one you don't want displayed?

Comment: Yes...? So just set one to `display:none` and the other to `display:block`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `' '` quotes to contain the values of your SVG code that you are putting inside the button using the inline JavaScript.

Why? Because you have your inline JavaScript inside `" "` of the `onClick` attribute, so the JS inside it uses `' '` for the variables, now if you are going to use `"` i.e double quotes to contain the values of attributes the parser will think that that double quote is the end of the `onClick` attribute.

Here's an example of what you need to have:

```
playButton2.innerHTML = '<svg width=\'100\' height=\'100\' version=\'1.1\' viewBox=\'-1 0 67 66\'><path d=\'M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z \' fill=\'orange\'></path><path d=\'M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z\' fill=\'black\'></path><path d=\'M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z\' fill=\'blue\'></path></svg>';
```

Each of the single quotes has a `\` before it to escape the character and tell the parser that it isn't the end of the quotes surrounding the variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

**In the first code we have the HTML for SVG inside the js**
https://jsfiddle.net/rvyv49oy/1/

```
 <button id="playButton2" style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer; background-color: black; border: 3px solid #0059dd;"
  onclick=" 
var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
var player = document.getElementById('player2');
player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
playButton2.innerHTML = '<svg width=\'100\' height=\'100\' version=\'1.1\' viewBox=\'-1 0 67 66\'><path d=\'M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z \' fill=\'red\'></path><path d=\'M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z\' fill=\'black\'></path><path d=\'M27.9,21h-3.7c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v22.8c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h3.7c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1V22.1 C29,21.5,28.5,21,27.9,21zM40.9,21h-3.7c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v22.8c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h3.7c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1V22.1 C42,21.5,41.5,21,40.9,21z\' fill=\'blue\'></path></svg> ';
player.play();
} else {
playButton2.innerHTML = '<svg width=\'100\' height=\'100\' version=\'1.1\' viewBox=\'-1 0 67 66\'><path d=\'M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z \' fill=\'orange\'></path><path d=\'M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z\' fill=\'black\'></path><path d=\'M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z\' fill=\'blue\'></path></svg>';
player.pause();
}">
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
<path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="orange"></path>
<path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
<path d="M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z" fill="blue"></path>
</svg>

</button>

<audio id="player2" style="display:none;">
  <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
</audio>
```

**Using display property, has it in the HTML button, only hidden**
https://jsfiddle.net/kLr5tLLe/1/

```
<button id="playButton2" style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer; background-color: black; border: 3px solid #0059dd;" onclick=" 
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .initial').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='none';
var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
var player = document.getElementById('player2');
player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
player.play();
} else {
document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='inline-block';
player.pause();
}">


  <svg style="display: none;" class="pause" width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
    <path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="red"></path>
    <path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
    <path d="M27.9,21h-3.7c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v22.8c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h3.7c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1V22.1 C29,21.5,28.5,21,27.9,21zM40.9,21h-3.7c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v22.8c0,0.6,0.5,1.1,1.1,1.1h3.7c0.6,0,1.1-0.5,1.1-1.1V22.1 C42,21.5,41.5,21,40.9,21z"
    fill="blue"></path>
  </svg>


  <svg style="display: none;" class="play" width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
    <path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="orange"></path>
    <path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
    <path d="M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z" fill="blue"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="initial" width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
    <path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="orange"></path>
    <path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
    <path d="M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z" fill="blue"></path>
  </svg>

</button>

<audio id="player2" style="display:none;">
  <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
</audio>
```