# Placing an SVG instead of a PNG in front of the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have been trying to figure out how to place an SVG play button instead of a png, but I can't seem to figure it out. That's basically all I'm trying to do here. I've been trying different things but nothing has been working.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/f6gvesLx/

**Play SVG**

```
<svg width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
<path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="orange"></path>
<path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
<path d="M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z" fill="blue"></path></svg>
```

**Below is the code format I'm using:**

```
   <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .outer {
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .tcell {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .wrap {
      max-width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      border: 0px solid #5CB378;
    }

    .inner {
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: black;
    }

    #thevideo, .image {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #000000;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #thevideo iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 0px;
    }

    .image {
      background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/400x400');
      background-size: cover;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }

    .image:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/WSlJUPf.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 24.5% Auto;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
    }
```

```
 <div class='outer'>
      <div class='tcell'>
        <div class='wrap'>
          <div class='inner'>
            <div class='image' onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
    thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('iframe').src =
    document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');"> </div>

            <div id='thevideo' style='display: none;'>

              <iframe frameborder='0'id='iframe' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/_0ZCVrg6Kzs?rel=0&keyboard=1&disablekb=1&vq=medium&showinfo=0&controls=1&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3&fs=0&wmode=transparent'></iframe></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path:

Remove the background image code from your css.
Then place your svg into your div that has the image class.
Then give the svg the image class as well.

Please refer to this JSFiddle that I forked: https://jsfiddle.net/0xehdwe7/

```
    <div class='outer'>
  <div class='tcell'>
    <div class='wrap'>
      <div class='inner'>
        <div class='image' onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo');
thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none';
document.getElementById('iframe').src =
document.getElementById('iframe').src.replace('autoplay=0','autoplay=1');">
          <svg class="image" width="100" height="100" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 67 66">
            <path d="M32.8,0.5C14.8,0.5,0.1,15.1,0.1,33.2c0,18.1,14.6,32.7,32.7,32.7c18.1,0,32.7-14.6,32.7-32.7 C65.5,15.1,50.9,0.5,32.8,0.5z " fill="orange"></path>
            <path d="M32.8,62.2c-16,0-29-13-29-29c0-16,13-29,29-29c16,0,29,13,29,29C61.8,49.2,48.8,62.2,32.8,62.2z" fill="black"></path>
            <path d="M46.2,31.9C44.7,31,27,19,26.1,18.4c-1.1-0.6-2.1,0.2-2.1,1.3v27c0,1.2,1.2,1.8,2.1,1.3c1.2-0.7,19.1-12.8,20.1-13.5 C47.1,33.9,47.1,32.5,46.2,31.9z" fill="blue"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>

        <div id='thevideo' style='display: none;'>

          <iframe frameborder='0' id='iframe' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/_0ZCVrg6Kzs?rel=0&keyboard=1&disablekb=1&vq=medium&showinfo=0&controls=1&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3&fs=0&wmode=transparent'></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have another question. Would you be able to help me with this? Adding an SVG that has 3 paths to the .innerHTML part of a button: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617768/adding-an-svg-that-has-3-paths-to-the-innerhtml-part-of-a-button

Comment: What if I want to keep:     .image {
      background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/400x400'); which would go behind the SVG, what would I change the code to then?